# Using different infinitive forms for the "unreal past" and "future"

Tags: adjectives, infinitives

I assume these three sentences below have the same meaning. Only the first one conveys the message that the action of sitting happens for a longer period. Am I right?

- I'd like to have been sitting there when she walked in.
- I'd like to be sitting there when she walked in.
- I'd like to be there, sitting when she walked in.

These sentences are refereeing to the unreal past. My second question is that weather it would be alright to just change

> when she walked in >

to

> when she walks in

and keep the rest of the sentences unchanged, to talk about a **wish**?

Comment: We never say "a same X".  Article use in English is very complicated, but one good rule is that it's always "**the** same", never *a* same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **to have been** is correct in the first part of your sentence when used with *when she walked in*.  We need to use *have been* because we are referring to an event in the past; saying *I'd like to be* expresses a wish about the present or future.

If you change *when she walked in* to *when she **walks** in*, you change the meaning of the sentence, from the past to the present tense.  The present tense can refer to a general truth (like *she walks in every day*) or a planned future event (like *she walks in at 8 o'clock tonight*).  If you use *she walks in*, then you have to wish *to be (sitting) there* to match.